# juju bootstap command goes from 'preparing...' to 'destroying..' (instance started ... but not deployed)

Tags: 16.04, juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to setup a MAAS, JUJU based openstack cloud, and can't seem to get the juju controller installed.

The *bootstrap* command seems to succeed on to the '*Preparing for Juju GUI 2.1.10 release installation*', but then moves on to 'destroying...' finally resulting with the error message:

> ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 failed to bootstrap model: bootstrap
>   instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "4y3h7q" is started but not deployed

Any hints on how to get a juju controller properly bootstrapped, or any debug steps that could be taken?

```
$ juju bootstrap mycloud-controller mycloud--upload-tools --show-log
2016-09-13 14:49:05 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:63 running juju [2.0-beta15 gc go1.6.2]
2016-09-13 14:49:05 INFO cmd cmd.go:141 Adding contents of "/home/phil/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
2016-09-13 14:49:05 INFO cmd cmd.go:141 Adding contents of "/home/phil/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
Creating Juju controller "mycloud-controller" on mycloud
2016-09-13 14:49:06 INFO juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:641 combined bootstrap constraints:
Bootstrapping model "controller"
Starting new instance for initial controller
Launching instance
2016-09-13 14:49:06 WARNING juju.provider.maas environ.go:717 no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node
 - 4y3h7q
2016-09-13 14:49:09 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:520 newest version: 2.0-beta15.1
2016-09-13 14:49:09 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:548 picked bootstrap tools version: 2.0-beta15.1
Building tools to upload (2.0-beta15.1-xenial-amd64)
2016-09-13 14:49:09 INFO juju.environs.tools build.go:170 found existing jujud
2016-09-13 14:49:09 INFO juju.environs.tools build.go:180 target: /tmp/juju-tools772659553/jujud
2016-09-13 14:49:25 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:322 built tools 2.0-beta15.1-xenial-amd64 (14941kB)
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Preparing for Juju GUI 2.1.10 release installation
2016-09-13 15:09:22 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:20 destroying model "controller"
2016-09-13 15:09:22 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:31 destroying instances
2016-09-13 15:09:22 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:51 destroying storage
2016-09-13 15:09:23 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 failed to bootstrap model: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "4y3h7q" is started but not deployed
```

juju version: 2.0-beta15-xenial-amd64

maas.log

```
Sep 13 23:49:06 agatha maas.node: [INFO] unfavoring-asha: Status transition from READY to ALLOCATED
Sep 13 23:49:07 agatha maas.node: [INFO] unfavoring-asha: allocated to user root
Sep 13 23:49:08 agatha maas.node: [INFO] unfavoring-asha: Status transition from ALLOCATED to DEPLOYING
Sep 13 23:52:04 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Sep 13 23:52:04 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading image descriptions from http://localhost:5240/MAAS/images-stream/streams/v1/index.json
Sep 13 23:52:05 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading boot resources from http://localhost:5240/MAAS/images-stream/streams/v1/index.json
Sep 13 23:52:05 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Writing boot image metadata and iSCSI targets.
Sep 13 23:52:05 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Installing boot images snapshot /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/snapshot-20160913-145205
Sep 13 23:52:16 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Updating boot image iSCSI targets.
Sep 13 23:52:17 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Cleaning up old snapshots and cache.
Sep 13 23:52:17 agatha maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images.
Sep 14 00:09:22 agatha maas.node: [INFO] unfavoring-asha: Releasing node
Sep 14 00:09:22 agatha maas.node: [INFO] unfavoring-asha: Status transition from DEPLOYING to RELEASING
Sep 14 00:09:22 agatha maas.node: [INFO] unfavoring-asha: Status transition from RELEASING to READY
```

**UPDATE**
I found that there is a `--keep-broken` option available for the `bootstrap` command, and reran bootstrap with this option:

```
Preparing for Juju GUI 2.1.10 release installation
2016-09-13 19:06:27 INFO juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:600 bootstrap failed but --keep-broken was specified so model is not being destroyed.
When you are finished diagnosing the problem, remember to run juju destroy-model --force
to clean up the model.
2016-09-13 19:06:27 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 failed to bootstrap model: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "4y3h7s" is started but not deployed
```

So my question is now, *how can I diagnose the problem in this broken image?*

Comment: Reran the process with the `--debug` option and no useful information is displayed....

Comment: upgraded to `2.0-beta18-xenial-amd64` from the `ppa:juju/devel` repository, and still seeing the same issue... although the debug information *before* the GUI installation is fuller, there's still no reason information between `INFO  cmd cmd.go:129 Fetching Juju GUI 2.1.10` to `INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:20 destroying model "controller"`